# Web2py Multilanguage

Tags: web2py

I'm trying to create a multilanguage page/wiki with wiki_plugin for web2py.
I know how to change/set my language, but i can't find any option to make multiple language version of a page.

Comment: I can't help you with your specific issue, but I can tell you that you'll get **great** web2py support at the web2py Google Group page (http://groups.google.com/group/web2py).  It is sort of the official support forum for web2py.  I much prefer the SO interface to Google Groups, but for web2py-specific issues the Google Group page is still the way to go.  Most questions there get answered within hours, usually by core developers.

Answer (score 3):

For an example, you might try looking at the code for the Admin app that comes with web2py (in /applications/admin/) -- the layout.html footer includes an option for the user to select the Admin interface language manually (unfortunately, this option does not appear to work in IE, though works in other browsers).